# Storing Date integer in SQLiteDatabase from original String value

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm using the [ExtendedCalendarView](https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView) library to store some information about events to be loaded into the calendar view.

As you can see from the documentation there are columns `startDate` `endDate` `start` and `end` which have the data type `INTEGER`

Now, my Event data is downloaded from a CSV file which my client provides and updates himself. All of the data is of type `String` so an example would be "26/04/2014".

How can I modify/convert the original `String` value to be inserted into my SQLite database for it to be accepted as an appropriate data type? Please see below the current conversion code and the error I'm getting.

```
public static int convertDateString(String dateString) throws ParseException {
    dateString = dateString.replace("/", "-");
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
    Date date = df.parse(dateString); //TURN STRING INTO DATE OBJECT

    String s = df.format(date);
    int result = Integer.valueOf(s);
    return result;
}
```

Error produced:

```
03-24 19:13:38.028: E/AndroidRuntime(10279): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "26.04.14"
03-24 19:13:38.028: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
03-24 19:13:38.028: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
03-24 19:13:38.028: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
03-24 19:13:38.028: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
03-24 19:13:38.028: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:490)
03-24 19:13:38.028: E/AndroidRuntime(10279):    at uk.ac.aber.dwd.CeredigionTourism.CalendarActivity.convertDateString(CalendarActivity.java:160)
```

Any help provided would be very much appreciated.

Comment: you got `NumberFormatException` because tried cast one date (26.04.14) to int, what you want to do?

Comment: SQLite can store dates in an integer or a string format... you choose. but a number with two dots is no number at all. it's not an int, not a float and not a double...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store a date as an `int` with the following `date.getTime();`.

Restore with `Date date = new Date(storedTime);`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that ExtendedCalendarView expects the dates in milliseconds since the epoch.
Try:

```
return date.getTime();
```